# Problems with Grails 404 UrlMapping

Tags: grails

I'm having some problems getting Grails to map my 404 errors to an errors controller like in the documentation. I'm running Grails 1.3.5 and when I add the following mapping to a default application:

"404" (controller:'errors', action:'notFound')

It works for mapping 500 errors but not 404's. I seem to recall having this problem before and it being related to Tomcat (vs Jetty) but I don't remember a fix or I thought it might have been resolved by now.

I try accessing a resource that's not defined like http://localhost:8080/appName/controllerName/blah and all I get is the default Tomcat 404.

I'm doing a standard *grails run-app* for testing and trying to get it to work.

Comment: I've now tried to reproduce the issue, practically, however, everything I tried (forward to a view, forward to controller/action; run-app, production mode WAR) worked as expected. Can you provide a reproducible test?

Comment: The issue isn't reproducible for me (tried a lot). - The questioner didn't provide feedback at all. - Voting the question down. - Thanks.

Comment: Breakthough! It seems to work for me if I redirect in the error controller method but not if I try to render a page. I will try and setup a bitbucket project and upload an example.

Comment: I'm getting this in Grails 1.3.6...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

after deleting whitespace, the problem solved

> "404"(controller:'errors', action:'notFound')

Comment: This sounds like an insane answer, but it worked for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

[http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-4232](http://web.archive.org/web/20110307090433/http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-4232) I think this is a known issue

Comment: I'd just converted the attached test case from Grails 1.1 to 1.3.5, and ran the WAR in Tomcat. - The issue doesn't appear to be reproducible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your application's *scripts/Events.groovy*:

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder

//modify the generated web.xml so that it supports being mapped to 'error'
eventWebXmlEnd = {String tmpfile ->
    //find the filter mapping to change
    String filterNm = "grailsWebRequest"
    def root = new XmlSlurper().parse(webXmlFile)
    def gwr = root."filter-mapping".find { it."filter-name" == filterNm }
    if (!gwr.size()) throw new RuntimeException(
        "[fail] No Filter named $filterNm")

    // xml is as expected, now modify it and write it back out
    gwr.appendNode {
        dispatcher("ERROR")
    }
    // webXmlFile is an implicit variable created before event is invoked
    webXmlFile.text = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
        mkp.declareNamespace("": "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee")
        mkp.yield(root)
    }
}
```

See [this post](http://amorproximi.blogspot.com/2008/07/more-on-grails-declarative-error.html) for an explanation. Note that I've copied the above script from that posting, but it had to be amended as the *web.xml*'s structure appears to have changed since the time of the posting's writing.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. - I did some actual testing now and found that this is not necessary with Grails 1.3.5. - Using a customized 404 mapping worked for me when forwarding to either a *view* or a *controller* and *action*. - Practically, I cannot reproduce any problems with 404 URL mappings in Grails.