# How to configure grails to always show own error page on status 500

Tags: security, tomcat, grails, error-handling

In `UrlMappings.groovy`, I have set `"500"(controller:'error', action:'error')` so that my own error controller (and view) is used.

It usually works, however when I tried tampering with the request input (submitting a parameter with 1MB size), I got a Tomcat generated error page with HTTP Status 500.

First I thought this error was only generated by Tomcat so that grails couldn't do anything about it, but the Exception is an `org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException` (nested Exception `java.lang.StackOverflowError`) and there are many `org.codehaus.groovy.grails` packaged Classes in the stack trace.

I think showing this Exception including stack trace to potential attackers is dangerous, so how I can I configure grails to always show my own error page? Or is it only possible to configure that in Tomcat?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that this is a Grails bug. I found [this Nabble thread](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/tomcat-error-500-handling-problems-JSecurity-related-td1360449.html) which directed me to [this JIRA issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-3219). That issue was resolved, but in the comments Peter Ledbrook linked to a [different JIRA issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-6987) that may or may not be your problem.

If that does look like what's happening for you, there's a workaround suggested in the comments, which can be found [here](https://github.com/alkemist/grails-error-pages-fix). The bug itself is scheduled to be fixed in 1.4; the fix workaround above is targeted for 1.3

Comment: I would like to try the fix, but when I run "grails install-plugin myFolder/grails-error-pages-fix.zip" grails seems to look for it online instead of using the local version. And it isn't available via the standard repository... it's only here on github: https://github.com/alkemist/grails-error-pages-fix Any idea how I can install it?

Comment: You can probably download the source (the Download button in the top-rightish), extract it, build it, and then install the plugin with the built distributable. I can't say I've ever installed a Grails plugin from Github, so I'm afraid I'm not the best to instruct you. But perhaps someone else can chime in.

Comment: I got it now using "install-plugin http://download.github.com/alkemist-grails-error-pages-fix-303f215.zip". But the installer fails saying "No plugin.xml descriptor found!" (and it's really not there). I guess it's not a real plug-in but has to be integrated into the project manually...

Comment: Thanks to a reply from the author, I got it working simply using "grails install-plugin error-pages-fix"! However I checked and it does NOT solve the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with Rob Hruska, having stumbled across most of his links myself.

I, too, suspect that the *grails-error-pages-fix* plugin ought to fix the issue - as the `grailsWebRequest` servlet by default doesn't have a `<dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>` assigned in *web.xml*.

The technique used with this plugin basically does the same as the technique that I'd suggested in a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181122/problems-with-grails-404-urlmapping/4183722#4183722). (Nevertheless, my own testings, as can be seen by my comments there, haven't led to consistent findings yet.)

Finally, one thing that would work at any rate is to implement a [custom servlet `Filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410808/how-do-i-catch-errors-globally-log-them-and-show-user-an-error-page-in-j2ee-app#2411006).

Comment: +1 For the custom Filter, I do that in most of my applications, since it provides more control (as opposed to letting the container handle your errors for you).