# Unable to create a 404 page in Grails

Tags: tomcat, grails, http-status-code-404

My mappings look like

```
static mappings = {
    "/"      (controller : "welcome",    action : "index")
    "/about" (controller : "welcome",    action : "about")
    "404"    (controller : "welcome",    action : "notFound")
}
```

This doesn't seem to catch 404 requests as I still get the default Tomcat 404 page. I have also tried the [closure based method](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-4232) (below) with no success.

```
    "404" {
        controller = "welcome"
        action = "notFound"
    }
```

Versions:

```
versions: {
app.version: "0.1"
app.servlet.version: "2.4"
app.grails.version: "1.3.5"
plugins.tomcat: "1.3.5"
plugins.hibernate: "1.3.5"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have succeeded by removing whitespace on the 404 line:

```
"404"(controller : "welcome",    action : "notFound")
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Grails are you running?

Also, what does your controller action look like? This person seems to have resolved the issue by using a redirect in their controller instead of a render:

[Problems with Grails 404 UrlMapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181122/problems-with-grails-404-urlmapping)

```
def notFound = {
  redirect(uri:"/404.html")
}
```

Comment: Version is in the original question: `app.grails.version: "1.3.5"`. I don't want to redirect to a static page, would like to render a specific error message in JSON (this is an API).

Comment: You could make a redirect to an uri, and have that uri render your controller and action. Perhaps this will solve your problem?

Comment: @sbglasius: No, because I don't want to issue a redirect. I want to display content with a 404 header.