# Grails: How do I map a 404 with /**

Tags: grails, action, http-status-code-404, url-mapping, wildcard-mapping

I've tried to create a custom 404 url mapping for URL's that are not found:

```
"/test" {
    controller="test"
}
"404" {
    controller="application"
    action="send404"
}
"500" {
    controller="application"
    action="send500"
}
```

But for some reason, the controller and action are never called. I get the default container 404 page. So, instead I tried:

```
"/test" {
    controller="test"
}
"/**" {
    controller="application"
    action="send404"
}
"500" {
    controller="application"
    action="send500"
}
```

Which seems to work fine, except that it also seems to call the send404 action on **every request**. For example, if I hit /test, I see the test page, but I also get the log statement I made in the send404() action.

Ideas appreciated...

Comment: I also notice that if I add a println() statment to both the TestController.index() and the ApplicationController.send500() actions, and then hit /test, both actions print to the console for the same request. Very strange. return() statement in the action didn't help...

Comment: Just make sure you looked on all the possiblities from http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/URL-Mapping-error-codes-td1354127.html

Comment: braces instead of brackets? as far as i have seen and used only brackets, never a closure. have you tried with brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it's favicon.ico that's being requested by the browser on each request that's causing this to happen.

```
// Route 404 to this action to see!
def send404() {

    log.error("404 Page Not Found! " + request.forwardURI)
    response.status = 404;
    render(view:"/application/not-found.gsp")        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried killing whitespace in your declaration, as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181122/problems-with-grails-404-urlmapping)?

```
"404"(controller:'application', action:'send404')
```

There is also an open issue [GRAILS-4232](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-4232) about this topic.

Comment: Yup, no such luck. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: I have it defined this way "/"{
            controller="login"
            action ="index"
        }
  "500"(view:'/error') and it works for me. After you define it this way, please make sure to do a grails clean. Also can you add these statements to the end.

Comment: In fact, that was the problem why "404" wasn't working, but that didn't stop /** from working. Turns out that there was a bloody favicon.ico being requested each time. See my post below.

Answer (score 1):

In grails, there is an ErrorController, the one that render stacktrace on 500, etc.

```
class UrlMappings {
  static mappings {
    "403" (controller: "error", action: "forbidden")
    "404" (controller: "error", action: "notFound")
    "500" (controller: "error", action: "internalError")
  }
}
```

And then, you can `render(controller:"error", action"notFound")` in another controller to stay RESTful. Or it will automagically render the notFound action of the error controller.

More details here : http://groovy.dzone.com/articles/grails-exception-handling-http

Comment: is there an actual ErrorController.groovy? From what I understand, we have to manually create an ErrorController.